# Implode function doesn't store data as expected

Tags: php, mysql, implode

I have already posted this but finally I didn't figure this out.I have a php form with some checkboxes (some of them are enabled and some disabled). Each of these has an id (id1=1, id2=2, id3=3, ...) which comes from database.

So when I submit the form I want to store these id's in a database table like this: if I choose only the 1st checkbox which has id=1 I should store '1' on my table and if I choose 1st and 3rd I should store '1, 3'. The problem is that I choose only the 1st and the stored data is '1, 2, 3, 4' because I have 4 checkboxes ENABLED.

PHP form :

```
<form method='post' action='insert.php'>
  .
  .
  .

 while($row_select4 = $stmt_select4->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

    if($form_points>=$row_select4['points']) {

         $points = $row_select4['points'];  


       echo '

          <div>
             <div class="feed-activity-list"><div style="border: 0.5px solid green; border-right-style:none;" class="input-group m-b"><span class="input-group-addon"> 
             <input type="checkbox" onclick="enable_form();" id="checkbox" name="opt[]" value="'.$points.'"></span>
             <input type="hidden" name="opt2[]" value="'.$row_select4['id'].'">


             <div class="feed-element">
             <a href="profile.html" class="pull-left">
             <img alt="image" class="img-circle" src="'. $row_select4['image_url']. '"
             </a>';
   ?>


   <button type="submit" id="submit" name="eksasrgirwsh" class="btn btn-w-m btn-primary">ΕΞΑΡΓΥΡΩΣΗ</button> 
             </form>
```

IMPLODE before insertion :

```
if(isset($_POST['opt2'])){



        foreach ($_POST['opt2'] as $value) {
            $gift = $_POST['opt2'];   

            $sliced = array_slice($gift, 0, -1);
            $gift_id = implode(", ", $sliced);
            }
```

And I store $gift_id in the table..

Check :

```
if(isset($_POST['opt'])){

        $total_points = 0;   
        $points =  array_values($_POST['opt']);



            foreach ($points as $value) {
                $total_points += $value;
                               }
             echo $total_points;




              $gift_ids = '';
              $gift = array_keys($_POST['opt']);

                foreach ($gift as $key => $value) {
                $gift_ids = $value;
                $gift_ids2 = implode(", ", $gift_ids);
                               }
                    echo $gift_ids2;

    }
```

Comment: So, what output are you getting / what is the error?

Comment: I want to store id's depending on which checkboxes user chooses.Now I store `1, 2, 3, 4` even if I choose only the checkbox with id=1..

Comment: `opt2` is an array of hidden fields with the same values as the checkboxes, but they're always sent, are you sure you shouldn't be using `opt` in your PHP?

Comment: No, but I use `opt[]` for another insertion..Isn't it a problem?

Comment: `opt[]` for points and `opt2[]` for gift_id

Comment: Then I for one have absolutely no idea what you question is actually asking...

Comment: I need to store two different values..Points of gift or gifts and which id has the chosen gift.The points stored correctly but I am facing problems when I need to store id's..Fox example : I choose the first gift with id=1, I submit the form and the stored id is `1, 2, 3, 4` insted of `1`

Comment: I completely agree with @JonStirling, opt2[] will always have as many elements as hidden controls. It will not be affected by the status of the checkbox.

Comment: So the method I use is not right..If you have any ideas please let me know.If I choose the 1st checkbox I want `1` to be stored, if I choose 1st,3rd,4th I want `1, 3, 4` to be stored.I just want to be clear..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using separate hidden controls to store the ids, use the name property of the checkboxes to do this:

```
'...
<input type="checkbox" onclick="enable_form();" id="checkbox" name="opt['. $row_select4['id'].']" value="'.$points.'"></span>
...';
```

The name of a checkbox will be like `name="opt[3]"` for id 3 record.

In the php script processing the form submission `array_keys($_POST['opt'])` will give you the gift ids, while `array_values($_POST['opt'])` will return the points. You will know which point is associated with which gift id because the keys of the $_POST['opt'] are the gift ids.

Pls also note that storing multiple values in a comma separated string in a single field is not really considered a good practice. You should normalise your data structure and store the separate values in separate records.

Comment: And I will need `foreach` to get the keys and the values..Am I right?

Comment: In your code I do not see if you updated the checkbox generation code. It's the one you used previously. If you do not update that part, then you cannot expect any change in the results, can you?